# Authenticating on MongoDB HTTPinterface or remote connection

Tags: mongodb

So I am trying to setup authentication on MongoDB instance. This is the first time doing this. I currently have an instance running off of localhost with no authentication. I have created users with admin rights as well as two users with readwrite rights. I have tried to log in to the httpinterface using these users but it doesn't let me in. Also, I am trying to create a connection from another server to this database instance but it does not allow me to. If i login to the server through SSH and authenticate on the mongo shell it works fine and returns 1. Any thoughts or suggestions?

I get the following error from the Mongo Connection:
array(2) { ["ok"]=> int(0) ["errmsg"]=> string(130) "Failed to connect to: IP:PORT: Authentication failed on database 'DB' with username 'User': auth failed" }
This user was just created and has readWrite rights and I know the password is correct.

Comment: Did you allowed the external access to mongoDB? it is disabled by default. It's on the bind_ip directive of your config file

Comment: Yes it is bound to the external IP of the machine. If I disable the authentication this all works perfectly fine.

Comment: What version is this? HTTP interface doesn't support the latest generation of auth, and the interface is deprecated (or going to be). I would avoid using it.

Comment: Oh. I am using Mongo 3.0.2 I was mainly using it to make sure the authentication worked so when I switched by website from running locally to running on two different servers but neither are working.